# Python functions in VSCode

Tags: python, function, visual-studio-code

I need help with running a python file in VSCode. At the moment I can right-click the file and choose "Run Python File in Terminal" and it works for the simple things like:

```
v = "Hello World"
print(v)
```

However, I want to run a function with user input and I just can't get it to work. Can someone tell me how it's done? Example of a function:

```
def userInput():
    v = input("What do you want to print? ")
    print(v)
```

Comment: It only defines the function, you never *call* it.

Comment: Can you show all of your code @YoungPadawan? Also, can you tell us which version of python you're running?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hello, and thank you for the answer. Maybe I can rephrase myself. After I have run the file, how do I call the function?

Comment: You need to run the function *in* the file, once the script finishes the Python process ends and the function no longer exists.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have the function in the file, but when I run the file nothing happens. Is there som way I have to run the file and choose to call the function at the same time?

Comment: @PeterDolan the function in the question is all the code I have in my file. I am currently using python 3.6.5.

Comment: You *define* the function in the file, but you don't *call* the function. Functions aren't called as part of being defined, that would be weird. Maybe Google "Python how to call function"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, based on what I've read in the comments this should fix things:

```
# yourfile.py

def userInput():
    v = input("What do you want to print? ")
    print(v)

userInput()
```

The final line actually calls the function, as opposed to just defining it. If this still gives you trouble, let me know and we can keep working through things!

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. I am used to Anaconda, where you can "call" the function from the console after you have run the file. but this clears it up!